# Python For Looping, Function Problems

Tags: python, function, pygame

I'm trying to create a little Guess The Flag game using Pygame and Python, but there's a problem with some for looping and and functions I've created. I'm relatively new to Python, and sometimes, I get very confused.

Anyway, I'm in  a testing part of my game and I've got four countries: China, Canada, USA, and France. I've put made them into separate defined functions, put them in a list and used the random module to shuffle the list. I've put it in a for loop, and I am trying to get it to work desiredly.

It properly shuffles the list and picks the function, but there are repeats of the same function and it never ends.

Here is my code:

```
def pick_country():
    global list1
    main_font = "brain flower euro.ttf"
    font1 = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 50)
    font2 = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
    list1 = [france1, canada1, china1, usa1]
    random.shuffle(list1)
    for cur_country in list1:
        cur_country()
    pygame.display.update()

def france1():
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    country = 'FRANCE'
    flag = 'france_flag.jpeg'
    flag1 = pygame.image.load(flag).convert()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                pick_country()
        screen.blit(flag1, (300, 350))
        pygame.display.update()
def canada1():
    name = ""
    main_font = "brain flower euro.ttf"
    font1 = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 50)
    country = 'CANADA'
    flag = 'canada_flag.jpeg'
    black = 0, 0, 0
    flag1 = pygame.image.load(flag).convert()
    while True:
        for evt in pygame.event.get():
            if evt.type == KEYDOWN:
                if evt.unicode.isalpha():
                    name += evt.unicode
                elif evt.key == K_SPACE:
                    name += " "
                elif evt.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                    name = name[:-1]
            elif evt.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(flag1, (200, 25))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (200, 115), (0, 115), (6))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (600, 115), (800, 115), (6))
        block = font1.render(name, True, black)
        rect = block.get_rect(center = (400, 600))
        screen.blit(block, rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (275, 550, 250, 100), (2))
        if name == "canada":
            pick_country()
        pygame.display.update()
def usa1():
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    country =  'USA'
    flag = 'usa_flag.jpeg'
    flag1 = pygame.image.load(flag).convert()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                pick_country()
        screen.blit(flag1, (225, 300))
        pygame.display.update()
def china1():
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    country = 'CHINA'
    flag = 'china_flag.jpeg'
    flag1 = pygame.image.load(flag).convert()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                pick_country()
        screen.blit(flag1, (300, 350))
        pygame.display.update()


pick_country()
```

Don't ask about Canada; it's my main country testing area.

Before you start with 'what have you tried', I have tried the following:

1: Taking the 'list and shuffle' part of the script and putting it outside the function, at the top of the screen.
1's Error: It doesn't know what the functions in the list are (yet).

2: Taking the 'list and shuffle' part of the script and putting it outside the function, after the country functions, yet before the actual `pick_country()`.
2's Error: It chooses the country at first, but it obviously never goes another one.

Any help? Please!

Comment: It might be a lot simpler to use an OO design here—a class with methods that access an instance attribute instead of a global.

Comment: I'm new to Python. I basically borrowed a book from the library, watched the thenewboston tutorials, and threw in a bit of Python Documentation here and there, and yeah. Could you explain a bit more, in detail?

Comment: Anyway, if you really want this answer, your "2" is the answer. The fact that you have _another_ problem after solving the first one doesn't mean that it isn't the solution to the first problem. That's how debugging usually goes.

Comment: Meanwhile… I can't write you a tutorial on how to use classes in SO answers. And I know nothing about thenewboston or what they do and don't teach you (although I'd be a bit surprised if you went through all of them and didn't know how to build classes, unless they really suck).

Comment: I understand what OO (Object Orientation) is, I understand, what classes are. I don't understand the instance attribute.

Comment: An instance attribute is… well, I don't know what terms your tutorial used. But if you have a member of an object, like `myobj.x`, that's an attribute; if each instance of the class has its own member (e.g., because you set it in the `__init__` method rather than in the class definition), it's an instance attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what's going on:

- `pick_country` calls `france1()`
- When the user hits a key, `pick_country()` is called again. This new call will start back at the first entry of your countries list, calling `france1()` again.
- When the user hits a key, call `pick_country()` again.
- Repeat ad infinitum

What you probably want is to `return` from each country's function when a key is pressed. This will bring you back to your original `pick_country` call, allowing it to move to the second country in the list.

Answer (score 1):

In each function you are calling pick_country() again

```
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    pick_country()
```

So, when the you run this function again, the for loop through the countries starts all over again.